# basic difference between i5 and i7 processors?

Tags: laptop, cpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Core i3 and core i5 processors. What is the difference? What do I choose?](https://superuser.com/questions/173666/core-i3-and-core-i5-processors-what-is-the-difference-what-do-i-choose)

I am planning to buy an HP desktop,  all the features are nice as far as I know but it doesn't have the latest i7 processors instead it has the **Intel Core i5 quad-core processors**.

Well, I am not an electronics guy so I would like to know does it really makes a big difference if I don't go for the i7 processor.

based on the differences between these two processors, is buying i5 going to be a bad idea as compared to i7 considering the performance of the PC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The big difference is Hyper-threading.

If you do not use a lot of "Threaded" applications which take advantage of this then get an i5 and save some cash.

Hyper-threading usually boosts the performance by around 20% if all threads are being used. At the moment unless your running lots of applications at once, doing large image processing through a program like Photoshop or video encoding then there would be little advantage in buying an i7 over an i5.

It might be worth investing more money in getting a faster (GHz) i5 than a slower (GHz) i7 :)

edit: overheating is not something to worry about in this case as and i5 or i7 with stock coolers run pretty cool.

Comment: +1I would just say perfect answer to my question.thanks

Comment: i5's and 7's have hyperthreading.

Comment: The mobile dual-core i5s do have hyper-threading, not the quad-core desktop i5s. Link -> http://www.intel.com/products/processor/corei5/index.htm

Comment: what would you recommend for visual studio ?

Comment: @Omu Get the best quad core you can afford (i5 desktop/i7 mobile), or if you can afford a more expensive desktop i7 with similar clock speed, get that.

Answer (score 3):

The i5 is of decent speed and value, if the i7 is a considerable amount more than the i5 then I'd go for the i5.

The i7 is usually a Quad core, split into 8 threads. This uses something called hyperthreading technology.

I have a i7 Laptop and even though it is very fast, I can think I can do with an i5 instead.

Hope I've helped.

Comment: hmm...So i7 wolud be costlier but much more faster I heard that hyperthreading causes more heating.don't know much..I could be wrong

Comment: Yeah my laptop does heat up a lot. And yes the i7 is faster

Answer (score 1):

There is unified socket and chipset, a turbo boost and new hyper threading.
[Here](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/hardware/articles/48391.aspx) you can find a  a quick run down.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon what you are going to be doing with it to be honest.  And in a store bought, HP computer, chances are good you arent going to be doing any hardcore gaming or making a huge use of multi-threaded applications.  Based on the VERY limited scope of what you are looking at, the i5 would be a decent choice.

Comment: francis i liked sidrans answer a lot(he deleted it) but I want to ask:he said that i5 has 4 cores and i7 has 6 i read somewhere adding more cores is at the cost of something..I guess it leads to overheating.correct me please

Comment: You cant add more cores to a CPU.  6 cores does run hotter than 4 sometimes, but that is really only if you went with an i7, not an i5.